# Abstract method not callable in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a base class which is abstract and the following prop definition and constructor:

```
protected abstract connectToFirebase: (config: any) => Promise<void>;
protected abstract listenForConnectionStatus: () => void;

constructor(config: IFirebaseConfig = {}) {
  if (config.mocking) {
    this._mocking = true;
    this.getFireMock();
  } else {
    this._mocking = false;
    this.connectToFirebase(config).then(() => this.listenForConnectionStatus());
  }
}
```

I want the concrete subclasses to have to define `connectToFirebase()` and `listenForConnectionStatus()` but sadly I'm doing something wrong here as I get the following error:

[image]

I'm still a little rough on the details of JS's class syntax so I'm not entirely sure if this is a TS or JS thing. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you declare it as an abstract method, it will be callable. But derived classes cannot set an abstract property before calling the base constructor - via `super`. That's the problem.

Comment: yes just as I was about to go to bed I realized ... thanks for your help

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1617#issuecomment-69215655

Comment: I‘m quite sure this is a TS thing, because Javascript is pretty flexible and it looks like it’s a error, that happens already in the Editor, right!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it as an abstract method rather than an abstract property:

```
protected abstract connectToFirebase(config: any): Promise<void>;
protected abstract listenForConnectionStatus: () => void;

constructor(config: IFirebaseConfig = {}) {
    this.connectToFirebase(config).then(() => this.listenForConnectionStatus());
}
```

The reason you can declare `listenForConnectionStatus` as an abstract property is because it's called within an arrow function. You would get an error if you tried to do this:

```
// Abstract property 'listenForConnectionStatus' in class 'Foo' cannot be accessed in the constructor.
this.connectToFirebase(config).then(this.listenForConnectionStatus);
```

---

The reason that there is a difference between the two is to do with how they are instantiated.

When declared as a property, your class extending the base class will look like this:

```
var Concrete = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Concrete, _super);
    function Concrete() {
        var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        _this.connectToFirebase = function (config) { return null; };
        return _this;
    }
    return Concrete;
}(Base));
```

As you can see, it calls `super` and **then** sets `_this.connectToFirebase`, so when `super` is called, `this.connectToFirebase` will be `undefined`.

Compare this to the compiled JavaScript for an abstract **method**:

```
var Concrete = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Concrete, _super);
    function Concrete() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Concrete.prototype.connectToFirebase = function (config) {
        return null;
    };
    return Concrete;
}(Base));
```

`connectToFirebase` is declared on the `prototype` at the same time that the constructor is declared. That means that when the constructor is actually called, it calls `super`, but `connectToFirebase` has already been defined and is available to use.